# Do Indian citizens need transit visa for Netherlands?

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, netherlands

My wife is a Indian passport holder and Permanent Resident of Canada. She is traveling from Canada to India via Amsterdam (Delta flight) and will have 1 hour 20 minutes layover at Amsterdam.

Will she require a transit visa for Amsterdam?

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please click the big checkbox to accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

No, your wife **doesn't need** an airport transit visa for Netherlands, as:

- she's not from Afghanistan, Bangladesh, Congo (Democratic Republic), Eritrea, Ethiopia, Ghana, Iran, Iraq, Nigeria, Pakistan, Somalia, Sri Lanka, Guinea, Guinea Bissau, Nepal, Sudan, Syria, South Sudan or Sierra Leone.
- even if she were from aforementioned countries, she is a permanent resident of Canada

Sources: [government.nl](https://www.government.nl/documents/forms/2015/11/26/list-of-airport-transit-visa-countries),
 [netherlandsandyou.nl](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/airport-transit-visa)